# Remove-Item not deleting files

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, delete-file

This is my PowerShell script:

```
$dir = ([io.fileinfo]$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition).DirectoryName

Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter *.png -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$_.Name -match ".+[\]]+.png"} | ForEach-Object {
    echo $_.FullName $(Test-Path $_.FullName)
    Remove-Item $_
    echo $_.FullName $(Test-Path $_.FullName)
}
```

The echos give actual filenames, but Test-Path resolves to False and nothing is ever deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Because your paths contain `]` which is interpreted by the `-Path` parameter (which you're using implicitly) as part of a pattern.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730956.aspx)

You should use the `-LiteralPath` parameter instead:

```
$dir = ([io.fileinfo]$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition).DirectoryName

Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter *.png -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$_.Name -match ".+[\]]+.png"} | ForEach-Object {
    echo $_.FullName $(Test-Path -LiteralPath $_.FullName)
    Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_
    echo $_.FullName $(Test-Path -LiteralPath $_.FullName)
}
```

Note that if you instead piped in the original object from `Get-ChildItem`, it would *automatically bind to `-LiteralPath`* so that's something to consider:

```
$dir = ([io.fileinfo]$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition).DirectoryName

Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter *.png -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$_.Name -match ".+[\]]+.png"} | ForEach-Object {
    echo $_.FullName $($_ | Test-Path)
    $_ | Remove-Item
    echo $_.FullName $($_ | Test-Path)
}
```

To prove this:

```
$dir = ([io.fileinfo]$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition).DirectoryName

$fileSample = Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter *.png -Recurse -File | 
    Where-Object {$_.Name -match ".+[\]]+.png"} | 
    Select-Object -First 1


Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding -Expression { 
    $fileSample.FullName | Test-Path 
} -PSHost  # $fileSample.FullName is a string, still binds to Path

Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding -Expression { 
    $fileSample | Test-Path 
} -PSHost  # binds to LiteralPath
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! Thank you so much. It works now!